# Run-tim error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: microsoft-word, activex, mendeley

I am using Word 2016 on my Win 7. When I click the `Reference` tab, I see the message of `Run-tim error '429': ActiveX component can't create object`

I then click `End`, and it can show the `Reference` content.

Then I click `Insert Citation` for my Mendeley, I see the problem as shown in the picture.

Can I ask how to deal with it? I tried unstall/reinstall the Mendeley, MS Word, still not work.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try repairing the Office installation via the Control Panel>Uninstall a Program .  Select Microsoft Office and then click on Change and select Repair.

Comment: this is the problem from Medeley, not from Office